# .NET EF Inheritance without keys or constraints

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

It is possible to inherit from a type in dotnet EF without inherit the keys, indexes, etc?

I have these types:

```cs
public class Product : IEntity<long>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVersion : Product
{
   [Key]
   public int ProductVersionId { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }   
}
```

I want `ProductVersion` to inherit all the properties from `Product` without creating any keys, constraints or navigation properties from the parent, just have the same properties and if are required or not, basically create a copy of the table columns.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it set up should remove the key constraint:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/data-annotations-key-attribute-in-ef-core/

Adding [NotInherritedAttribute] should get rid of any of restraints you add:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=net-6.0

```
[NotInheritedAttribute]
public class ProductVersion : Product{
    [Key]
    public int ProductVersionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } 
}
```